# Decoding the Ceasar Cipher Ends Up with Logic Error

Tags: python, decoding, caesar-cipher, logic-error

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to coding, I was training in CodeWars when I came across this question:

> The soldiers of a country use ceasar cipher for messaging. Only letters are changed and everything else is not touched in these messages (like "!" and space). Each message is split into 4 or 5 parts and each part is carried by one runner.  The first part starts with 2 letters: The first one shows a random letter and the second one is the same letter that has been changed by shifting (so that the soldiers know the number of the shift). Now write a code for decoding and encoding the message `I should have known that you would have a perfect answer for me!!!`

The encoding function works. However, the following function that I wrote for decoding does not. I enter the `"ijJ tipvme ibw", "f lopxo uibu z", "pv xpvme ibwf ", "b qfsgfdu botx", "fs gps nf!!!"` message and I'm supposed to get `I should have known that you would have a perfect answer for me!!!`, but instead I get some nonsense message saying `'ž~ ¨¤ª¡™ –«', ' "š  £¤¬£ ©–© ®', ' "¤ª ¬¤ª¡™ –«š ', ' "– ¥š§›š˜© –£¨¬', ' "š§ ›¤§ ¢š!!!`

I import `re` first:

```
import re
```

Here's the function:

```
def decode(arr):
    arr = str(arr) #turn what we have into str
    array = list(re.split('",', arr)) #get rid of the ' ", ' between every part so that
                                # it will be a single whole messege in the end and also turn it into
                                #a list in which every item is a single part

    decoded_messege = ""

    first_messege = list(array[0]) #turns the first part into a list of letters
    letter_shift = ord(first_messege[1]) - ord(first_messege[0]) #realizes the number of shift

    for messege in array:
        for letter in messege:
            if (ord(letter) > 122 or ord(letter) < 65): #the letter is not an alphabet (a space or !)
                decoded_messege += letter

            else: #the letter is an alphabet
                decoded_messege += chr(ord(letter) - letter_shift) #the ascii code is the current ascii number
                                                                #minus the shift

    decoded_message = decoded_messege[2:] #ignore the first two letters that are
                                        #only for showing shift and don't matter in the message
    return decoded_messege
```

Comment: Odd. The code logic is correct and it works when I test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're taking into account the first two characters to calculate the shift: `"`-->`"`, which is 0. Change it to `arr = str(arr)[2:]`
Also, the return should be at the same level of the first loop.

````py
import re


def decode(arr):
    arr = str(arr)[2:] #turn what we have into str
    array = list(re.split('",', arr)) #get rid of the ' ", ' between every part so that
                                    # it will be a single whole messege in the end and also turn it into
                                    #a list in which every item is a single part

    decoded_messege = ""

    first_messege = list(array[0]) #turns the first part into a list of letters
    letter_shift = ord(first_messege[1]) - ord(first_messege[0]) #realizes the number of shift

    for messege in array:
        for letter in messege:
            if letter != '"':
                # print(letter)
                if (ord(letter) > 122 or ord(letter) < 65): #the letter is not an alphabet (a space or !)
                    decoded_messege += letter
                else: #the letter is an alphabet
                    decoded_messege += chr(ord(letter) - letter_shift) #the ascii code is the current ascii number                                                                    #minus the shift
        decoded_message = decoded_messege[2:] #ignore the first two letters that are
                                            #only for showing shift and don't matter in the message
    return decoded_messege

print(decode('""ijJ tipvme ibw", "f lopxo uibu z", "pv xpvme ibwf ", "b qfsgfdu botx", "fs gps nf!!!""'))
# hiI should hav e known that y ou would have  a perfect answ er for me!!!
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate the answer. However, I still have a problem: How can I get rid of the "hi" before the message? It's supposed to be the decode of the "ij" the message starts with. Shouldn't (decoded_message = decoded_messege[2:]) part of the code get rid of it? Why is it still there?

Comment: Fix the spelling in the decoded_messege variable. You gave `messege` and `message`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a life saver. This just shows how being careless messes up your work.